# Is it ever specifically mentioned that Dumbledore and Grindelwald had a romantic relationship?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, fantastic-beasts, gellert-grindelwald

When I read the Harry Potter books, I never put two and two together to realize that Dumbledore and Grindelwald had anything more than a platonic relationship. It was many years later when JKR said something about it in an interview (one which came out sometime after the Fantastic Beasts movie) that I knew that there was. 
Is it ever mentioned in an *obvious* way in the books that there was something between them? Were they a couple, or was it just that Dumbledore had feelings for Grindelwald?

Comment: Do you have a link to the interview you mention? I only know of JKR saying "BTW Dumbledore's gay, please like me."

Comment: Yup, here's an excerpt: "But Rowling’s penchant for revisionist history has since added an extra dimension to Dumbledore’s motivations in these dark interim years: in 2007, she declared that Dumbledore was gay and had in fact fallen in love with Grindelwald in his youth." from https://www.thedailybeast.com/the-fantastic-beasts-shock-ending-what-it-means-for-the-future-of-the-potterverse

Comment: @krishna, note that 2007 was not “after the Fantastic Beasts movie”. :-)

Comment: whoops I must have read it after I saw the movie. possibly it was a different article but you get the gist. JKR does state that Dumbledore had romantic feelings towards Grindelwald, which until then I didn't know.

Comment: Well, see, only Snape can put two and two together.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Dumbledore's love was unrequited (and unsaid in the books).

There's nothing in the books that explicitly say that Dumbledore had any sort of romantic feelings towards Grindelwald, the way other relationships or feelings are confirmed explicitly in the text itself.

The first time Dumbledore being gay is explicitly mentioned is in [this interview](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more/) with JKR.

> JKR: My truthful answer to you… I always thought of Dumbledore as gay. Dumbledore fell in love with Grindelwald, and that that added to his horror when Grindelwald showed himself to be what he was. To an extent, do we say it excused Dumbledore a little more because falling in love can blind us to an extent?

In another, later, interview, JKR seems to state that Grindelwald didn't feel the same way, but would have likely used Dumbledore's feelings to manipulate him.

> JKR: I think he was a user and a narcissist and I think someone like that would use it, would use the infatuation. I don't think that he would reciprocate in that way, although he would be as dazzled by Dumbledore as Dumbledore was by him, because he would see in Dumbledore, 'My God, I never knew there was someone as brilliant as me, as talented as me, as powerful as me. Together, we are unstoppable!' So I think he would take anything from Dumbledore to have him on his side. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Harry, A History](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tlLz230-KAUC&pg=PT465&lpg=PT465&dq=I%20don%27t%20think%20that%20he%20would%20reciprocate%20in%20that%20way,%20although%20he%20would%20be%20as%20dazzled%20by%20Dumbledore&source=bl&ots=0WRzqYc1lh&sig=ENM0fbve0noY101l2tpLlFu3eUc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim-5KMzbnZAhViCcAKHdwKDMMQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=I%20don%27t%20think%20that%20he%20would%20reciprocate%20in%20that%20way%2C%20although%20he%20would%20be%20as%20dazzled%20by%20Dumbledore&f=false)*</sup></sub>

He would have found Dumbledore very interesting, and considering him an equally talented ally worth having, but not reciprocated his romantic feelings.

## But, JKR now implies a mutual relation.

However, in the “Fantastic Beasts: Crimes of Grindelwald” DVD extras, JKR is now implying that Grindelwald and Dumbledore were in a more mutual relationship.

> "Their relationship was incredibly intense, it was passionate — and it was a love relationship," the author said. "But as happens in any relationship, gay or straight or whatever label we want to put on it, one never knows really what the other person is feeling. You can't know. You can believe you know."
>
> "So I'm less interested in the sexual side — though I believe there is a sexual dimension to this relationship — than I am in the sense of the emotions they felt for each other, which ultimately is the most fascinating thing about all human relationships." 
> <sub><sup>*[- J.K. Rowling gave more insight into the 'passionate' relationship between Dumbledore and Grindelwald, and confirmed it had a 'sexual dimension' (Insider)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tlLz230-KAUC&pg=PT465&lpg=PT465&dq=I%20don%27t%20think%20that%20he%20would%20reciprocate%20in%20that%20way,%20although%20he%20would%20be%20as%20dazzled%20by%20Dumbledore&source=bl&ots=0WRzqYc1lh&sig=ENM0fbve0noY101l2tpLlFu3eUc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim-5KMzbnZAhViCcAKHdwKDMMQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=I%20don%27t%20think%20that%20he%20would%20reciprocate%20in%20that%20way%2C%20although%20he%20would%20be%20as%20dazzled%20by%20Dumbledore&f=false)*</sup></sub>

This is a clear change from her saying that she did not think that he would reciprocate in that way.

Comment: The second quote seems to be from the interview Melissa Anelli did for her Harry A History book.

Comment: So was Grindelwald gay or wasn't he?

Comment: @HarryWeasley No interview I've found addresses whether Grindelwald is gay. JKR said he didn't reciprocate Dumbledore's feelings, but whether that's because he wasn't gay isn't said. He could have just not been into Dumbledore, or not be interested in romance at all.

Comment: @Bellatrix Sounds pretty plausible for someone who is a predecessor for the Dark Lord! :P Nice answer BTW, (+1)!

Answer (score 16):

#### No, it is never said they had a relationship. It is only said that Dumbledore had (probably) unrequited feelings for Grindelwald.

The best we get from the books is the following quote:

> It can now be revealed that Grindelwald chose to visit his great aunt in Godric’s Hollow, and that there, intensely shocking though it will be for many to hear it, he struck up a close friendship with none other than Albus Dumbledore.
> <sub>*Deathly Hallows - Chapter 18: The Life and Lies of Albus Dumbledore*</sub>

The first time a romantic relationship was mentioned between the two was when JKR did a reading of *Deathly Hallows* at Carnegie Hall in 2007. Specifically during the QnA afterwards.

> The question was: Did Dumbledore, who believed in the prevailing power of love, ever fall in love himself?
>
> JKR: My truthful answer to you… I always thought of Dumbledore as gay. [ovation.] … Dumbledore fell in love with Grindelwald, and that that added to his horror when Grindelwald showed himself to be what he was. To an extent, do we say it excused Dumbledore a little more because falling in love can blind us to an extent? But, he met someone as brilliant as he was, and rather like Bellatrix he was very drawn to this brilliant person, and horribly, terribly let down by him. Yeah, that’s how i always saw Dumbledore. In fact, recently I was in a script read through for the sixth film, and they had Dumbledore saying a line to Harry early in the script saying I knew a girl once, whose hair… [laughter]. I had to write a little note in the margin and slide it along to the scriptwriter, “Dumbledore’s gay!” [laughter] “If I’d known it would make you so happy, I would have announced it years ago!”
> <sub>[the-leaky-cauldron.org](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more/)</sub>

In a later interview in 2010, JKR said that Grindelwald probably didn't requite Dumbledore's feeling.

> JKR: [re: Grindelwald] I think he was a user and a narcissist and I think someone like that would use it, would use the infatuation. I don't think that he would reciprocate in that way, although he would be as dazzled by Dumbledore as Dumbledore was by him, because he would see in Dumbledore, 'My God, I never knew there was someone as brilliant as me, as talented as me, as powerful as me. Together, we are unstoppable!' So I think he would take anything from Dumbledore to have him on his side.
> <sub>[Interview with Melissa Anelli](https://web.archive.org/web/20100213150920/http://www.harryahistory.com/2010/02/vault-xx-dumbledore-and-grinde.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Love and passion are two different things. JK didn't contradict herself in her previous two answers. She said she saw Gellert as a narcissist. A narcissist wouldn't be opposed to sex with someone who is willing.

To me it reads as if Gellert was purely for the physical and intellectual part, while Albus was the one who was truly in love. It was a sexual relationship but each had their own feelings about it. JKR said as much. The one that had more to lose in this  was dumb young Albus.

Comment: You posted this as an answer, but rather than addressing the question itself, you appear to be primarily concerned with arguing that JKR didn't contradict herself with her various statements, which is not what the question was asking about. If you're going to post an answer, please focus on answering the actual question. If you just want to comment on another answer, you need to earn some more [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) first in order to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege.